# Why is @try not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, try-catch

I have a sensitive method that is doing operations with numbers and arrays. At one point I have something like this:

```
@try {

CGFloat value = [myArray[index] floatValue];

...

@catch (NSException *exception) {
   [self doSomething];
}

@finally {
}
```

If index is a negative value or a value out of myArray range, I want an exception to be thrown, or in other words, I want @catch to run, but it is not working, the app simply crashes when such conditions occur.

Yes, I know I can test the whole thing with `if` but I am trying to avoid using `if` (don't ask me why).

Why and how do I solve that?

Comment: Show the rest of the `try/catch` block.

Comment: BTW - Checking with an `if` is the proper solution even if you want to avoid it.

Comment: What's the type of `myArray`?

Comment: I don't want to use `if`. Too easy to be patched. `catch` does not matter if the code is not going there.

Comment: myArray is an array of numbers. Code corrected.

Comment: @SpaceDog Is this an `NSArray *myArray =...` or `NSNumber *myArray[N]`?

Comment: You still haven't posted the rest of the `try/catch` block.

Comment: @maddy - does it matter? The line in question is the one crashing. Nothing below that line matter. That line is the one that should throw the error. This is the line I want to trigger the `@catch`.

Comment: Make sure the `@catch` block can handle the type of error the system is throwing due to your LOC. A generic type 'NSException' may be useful.

Comment: @SpaceDog Yes it matters. How do you expect people to help you debug your code when you refuse to post the code you need help with? At least show the `@catch` block.

Comment: Also provide details about the exception that crashes your app.

Comment: Do not try to use exceptions in Objective-C. Exceptions in Objective-C are reserved for non-recoverable programming errors not program control. In addition objects are not cleaned-up when the throw is across stack frames which will lead to memory corruption.

Comment: In case Zaph didn't say it clearly enough, **Don't use *try/catch**!*  It should only be used by people who *really* know what they're doing.  (Yes, this bugs me a little bit too, but it's the way it is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It crashes because the array in question does not range check the index. Only certain types of 'managed' arrays check the index. For example, NSArray will throw an NSRangeException. A regular C array such as int myarr[5] will not.

Comment: That's it. The array in question is a C array. I forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C does not raise exceptions when you access elements outside the range of built-in arrays; it remains undefined behavior - i.e. the way it is in "plain" C.

Using `NSArray` in place of a "plain C" array will fix the problem:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@1, @3, @20];
@try {

CGFloat value = [myArray[index] floatValue];

...

@catch (NSException *exception) {
   [self doSomething];
}

@finally {
}
```

Comment: Except exceptions are not designed to be used as program control in Objective-C.

Comment: @Zaph Of course they are not! It looks like OP is pretty clear on that, asking the question out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried the following and successfully got the "exception!" printed out.

```
NSInteger i = -1;
NSArray *array = @[];
@try {
    CGFloat value = [array[i] floatValue];
}
@catch (NSException *e) {
    NSLog(@"exception!");
}
```

There is obviously something wrong in what you are doing (that you didn't put in your question).

Comment: The OP left out the extremely important detail that the array is a C array and not an NSArray.